# Error in Geofire: 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, geofire

I ran a pod install on GeoFire today and the error occurred.

> 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found

The error is happening in the GeoFire.m file.

***GeoFire.m***

```
#import "GeoFire.h"
#import "GeoFire+Private.h"
#import "GFGeoHash.h"
#import "GFQuery+Private.h"
#import <Firebase/Firebase.h> // Error Here
```

***Podfile.m***

```
use_frameworks!
target 'EventsWithFriends' do
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.4'
pod 'Bolts', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.2.0'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.1.4'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.10.1'
pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.3.1'
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
pod 'JTCalendar', '~> 2.0'
pod 'CTAssetsPickerController',  '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'TapjoySDK'
pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AACollageView'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
end

target 'EventsWithFriendsTests' do

end
```

***Screenshot of error***
[image]

Comment: Did you try to build the project? After you add a dependency to the project you have to build them to import properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure to update the latest version of FireBase, that fixed the issue.